# Copy Command On ContextMenu over TextBlock inside DataGridTemplateColumn

Tags: wpf, xaml, contextmenu, copy-paste

Thought of asking because never done this before on a TextBlock. I Am not able to copy the content of the DataGridTemplateColumn where it has a TextBlock in that and i have assigned a context menu to that.

The copied content is blank.

When I tried in MS word is Blank Cell.

My Template Column and ContextMenu are as below.

I Tried using TextBox But it work when the textbox is enabled and in-spite of grid column is readonly. It allows editing and when we disable it won't copy  the text.

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Details" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True">
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
           <Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding details}" TextWrapping="Wrap">
              <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                 <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="Copy" Command="Copy"></MenuItem>    
                 </ContextMenu>   
              </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
             </TextBlock>
           </Grid>
   </DataTemplate>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why the copied content is empty string is that TextBlock does not support Copy, Cut and Past Commands like **TextBox**. So If using TextBlock, you'll need to support these commands manually, but you can use TextBox to support the copy command, which could act as TextBlock. Please check the following.

```
<TextBox Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Text="{Binding details}" IsReadOnly="True" TextWrapping="Wrap">
    <TextBox.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Copy" Command="Copy"></MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
    </TextBox.ContextMenu>
</TextBox>
```

---

[updated]

First of all, the code below can be executed correctly?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Text="test" IsReadOnly="True" TextWrapping="Wrap">
            <TextBox.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="Copy" Command="Copy"></MenuItem>
                </ContextMenu>
            </TextBox.ContextMenu>
        </TextBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: It Still Isn't working... I tried it it gives me a blank copied Cell

Comment: @DOTNETBEE: In my case, this has been correctly performed. Please try with setting Text by a string value instead of Binding as the updated answer code.

Comment: @DOTNETBEE: I do not fully understand your meaning. What does `if we disable the textbox then it does not work` mean?

Comment: It worked that's y i have excepted the answer sorry for the confusion this undo changes did all that.. Sorry for that IsReadOnly did that work for me.

Comment: @DOTNETBEE: No problem. Enjoy your coding:)

Answer (score 0):

In my particular case, I fixed the issue by:

- Removing `IsReadOnly` from the row.
- Instead of using `Command=Copy`, I used `Command="{Binding CopyToClipboard}"` with a binding of the command to the ViewModel behind the row.