# ContextMenu only on specific TreeViewItem

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, contextmenu, treeviewitem

Is there any possible solution to show custom ContextMenu on specific TreeViewItem?

My TreeView looks like that:

```
<TreeView Name="AliasTree" ItemsSource="{Binding aliases}">
    <TreeView.Resources >
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:ConnectionModel}"  ItemsSource="{Binding schemas}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding alias}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:SchemaModel}"      ItemsSource="{Binding schema_collections}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SCHEMA_NAME}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>


        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:SchemaCollection}"      ItemsSource="{Binding collection}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding  SCHEMA_COLLECTION_NAME}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate> 

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:TableModel}" >
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TABLE_NAME}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

I want to show ContextMenu only on TreeViewItem based on "TableModel".
Later I will make custom ContextMenu for other elements.

How can I do that?

Thank You for any help,
Wiktor

Comment: useTextBlock.ContextMenu in your template. just like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7909390/copy-command-on-contextmenu-over-textblock-inside-datagridtemplatecolumn

Comment: @Mat : Thank You! Its worked :)